# Eliminar elemento array con splice en angular 12

Tags: javascript, array, angular

tengo un problema cuando quiero eliminar un elemento de un array

esta es mi funcion para eliminar las imagenes del array

```
 removeImage(url: any) {
    this.sendImage.splice(this.sendImage.indexOf(url), 1);
    this.patchValues();
  }
```

Lo que me sucede es que .indexOf no me esta ubicando tal cual quiero en la posicion del array, entonces me borra una siguiente o una anterior en vez de la que estoy señalando

mi html:

```
 <div class="preview-wrapper">
          <div class="img-preview" *ngFor="let url of images">
            <div class="image">
              <img [src]="url" width="200px" />
            </div>
            <button
              type="button"
              mat-button
              class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
              (click)="removeImage(url)"
            >
              Eliminar
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

asi es como obtengo el array al subir las fotos:

```
        this.sendImage.push({
          data: result,
          filename: filename,
          mime: mime,
        });
        this.patchValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale la ubicación directa con `let i = index`

```js
removeImage(i: number) {
  this.sendImage.splice(i, 1);
  this.patchValues();
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-wrapper">
  <div 
    class="img-preview" 
    *ngFor="let url of images; let i = index">
    <div class="image">
      <img [src]="url" width="200px" />
    </div>
    <button 
      type="button" 
      mat-button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"          
      (click)="removeImage(i)">
              Eliminar
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esa fue la solucion que buscaba, saludos